# I want to modify the data in my object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var todate = Filters.Where(it => it.Value == "ApplicationDateToSearch").Select(it =>
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(it.Description, out DateTime ConvertedToDate))
                    {
                        it.Description = ConvertedToDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59).ToString();
                    }
                })?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Visual Studio doesn't seem to like this.

```
List<EmployeeRole> Filters

public class EmployeeRole
{         
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: LINQ stands for "language integrated query", meaning that it's intended for obtaining data. Can you offer any reason why you want to use it to make modifications? Also, `List<T>` implements a `.ForEach` method that you could use. Anyway, "Visual Studio" doesn't "like" it because your projection (`.Select`) doesn't return anything.

Comment: Define "doesn't like this". Did you forget to do `return it;` after the `if`?

Comment: Also, the way you are adding hours, seconds etc is wrong (since it won't handle one tick before midnight, for example). Don't do that. Add an entire day and use `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your `selector` doesn't return any value. The compiler is unable to build that due to the unspecified return value. This hasn't to do anything with modifying your instance. `return it;` as last line in your lambda should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'select' statement is used to select the properties you can't modify in that, so you have to use the 'ForEach' statement for that. But 'ForEach' statement doesn't have any return type so after that you can use FirstOrDefault

```
var x = Filters.Where(i => i.Value == "ApplicationDateToSearch").ToList();
x.ForEach(i => i.Description = DateTime.TryParse(i.Description, out DateTime ConvertedToDate) ?                             ConvertedToDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59).ToString() : string.Empty);
var todate = x.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: _"If you don't want to modify the existing list then use like this"_ - if you mean the entities, then they will be modified even using your code [example](https://rextester.com/UIZS10704).

Comment: Yes, i agree it will modify the data list, I'll change the text